# MongoDB_Join Functionality

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB, here I need to form a new table from different collections where it should look like this,

```
userId   userName    email    phone     role
```

Here according to `userId`, I need all information from different Collections.

Data:

```
> db.userinfo.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
        "userId" : "AD",
        "phone" : "0000000000"
}
> db.userrole.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
        "userId" : "AD",
        "role" : "admin"
}
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
        "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
        "userId" : "AD",
        "userName" : "admin"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a standard lookup to join. Refer [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.userinfo.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "userrole",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "roleJoin"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "userJoin"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3l5_zTkK4fA)**